# How to customize Directions widget of ArcGIS Viewer for Flex 3.4 using Flash Builder 4.6?

Tags: widget, arcgis-flex-viewer, flash-builder

I want to customize the Directions widget in order to be suitable for my application.

However, I do not know how to show a Directions widget without signing in to resources in http://www.arcgis.com.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: you would need the src code to pull it into flashbuilder

Comment: hi Brad,i did not understand if you can plz explain more.Thanks

Comment: there are 38 results for directions with the tools filter. there are 597 results on apps for directions.  you need to plz explain more.

Answer (score 1):

Flex is asking for an ArcGIS login because the default Network Route Service requires an organizational account which uses credits. Make your own Network Route Service and use that in combination with the free ArcGIS Online World Geocoding Service.